# Insert values from a linked list to a stack

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I am building a programm in C and I want to insert 100 random values from 0-20 into a linked list. After that I want those values to be pushed in a stack with the same order that were inserted into the list. Can anybody point me how to?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode{
       int data;
       struct listNode * nextPtr;
};



struct stackNode {
 int data;
 struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};


typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode* StackNodePtr;


typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode * ListNodePtr;

void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info);
void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr);

void insert(ListNodePtr *, int);
void printList(ListNodePtr);

int main(void)
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr=NULL;
    ListNodePtr startPtr1=NULL;
    StackNodePtr stackPtr = NULL;
    int item, i;


    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    item = rand() % 20;
    insert(&startPtr,item);
    }
    printList(startPtr);

    while(startPtr){
         push(&stackPtr,startPtr->data);
         startPtr=startPtr->nextPtr;
    } 
    printStack(stackPtr);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr,int value)
{
     ListNodePtr newPtr,previousPtr,currentPtr;
     newPtr = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
     if(newPtr!=NULL){
                      newPtr->data=value;
                      newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;


                      previousPtr=NULL;
                      currentPtr=*sPtr;

                      while(currentPtr!=NULL && value>currentPtr->data){
                                                                       previousPtr=currentPtr;
                                                                       currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
                                                                       }
                      if(previousPtr==NULL){
                                            newPtr->nextPtr=*sPtr;
                                            *sPtr=newPtr;
                                            }
                      else{
                           previousPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
                           newPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr;
                           }
                      }
                      else
                          printf("%d not inserted! No memory!\n",value);
}

void printList(ListNodePtr c)
{
     if(c==NULL){
                 printf("List is empty\n");
                 }else{
                       printf("The List is:\n");
                       while(c!=NULL){
                                      printf("%d --> ",c->data);
                                      c=c->nextPtr;
                                      }
                                      printf("NULL\n\n");
                       }
}

void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, int info) {
    StackNodePtr newPtr;
    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    if(newPtr!=NULL) {
        newPtr->data=info;
        newPtr->nextPtr=*topPtr;
        *topPtr=newPtr;
    } else
        printf("%d not inserted. No "
        "memory.\n", info);
}

void printStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr) {
     if (currentPtr == NULL) {
        printf("Stack is empty.\n\n");
     } else {
         printf("The stack is:\n");
         while (currentPtr != NULL) {
         printf("%d --> ", currentPtr->data);
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         }
         printf("NULL\n\n");
     }
}
```

i actually did this and now whatever integer is inserted into the list it is inserted into the stack as well but in reverse order.

Comment: i insert 100 random values from 0-20 in a linked list.. now i want the same values to be inserted in the same order into the stack via the push function..

Comment: Your code doesn't create a linked list of randoms from 0..20; they're from 0..18. That said, throw out the second for-loop and move the stack `push()` call to the same loop body as the list `insert()`. This, assuming your functions actually work, which I leave to you to address if they do not. The plethora of other things wrong in the code are a different issue than your question, which is somewhat nebulous to begin with.

Comment: What is your question ? What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: well i did this and all i get is the list created with random numbers and in stack i get the number 11 all the time..I want every number that is inserted into the list to be inserted into the stack as well with the same exact order....is this possible???

Comment: @user3277037 *read my prior comment*.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the second loop inserts the integer (Item) which was generated in last iteration of first loop. Since it remains the same, all items of stack are same. Place the push statement in the first loop and you will be fine.

```
int item, i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    item = rand() % 19;
    insert(&startPtr,item);
}
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    push(&stackPtr, item);
}
```

just do this :

```
int item, i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    item = rand() % 19;
    insert(&startPtr,item);
    push(&stackPtr, item);
}
```

Since your insert and Push are causing the list and stack to be in reverse order. What you can do is this:

Create and array of size 100. 
Initialize the array with 100 random values (I hope I do not need to give code for this)
Then, if the name of this array is randArray, write this code:

```
int item, i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    item = randArray[i];
    insert(&startPtr,item);
    item = randArray[99-i];
    push(&stackPtr, item);
}
```

What I am doing is that I am inserting the random values in the stack in reverse order to that of list.

Code for initializing array of random ints:

```
   srand(time(NULL));
   int a[100] = {[0 ... 99] =1};
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        a[i]=rand()%19;
        printf("%i \n",a[i]); // comment this line it is just for printing
   }
```

Comment: well i did but the numbers in the stack are not in the same order as they are in the list...this is what i want to do.

Comment: Print the stack in reverse order !, it really depends on how your insert code is working for list and stack.

Comment: how can i print the stack in reverse order? my code is above can you check this out?

Comment: In your list insert function, you are adding the new node at the end of list, while in Push function of your stack, you add the new node at start of list. That is why the list is reverse order of stack. Now if you do not want to change the implementation, you can insert in another way, see my answer edit.